# No visible @interface for 'UIAlertView' declares the selector :NSString stringWithUTF8String

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uialertview

i have an error which i donno how to fix it it's making me crazy. i have searched about the solution a lot but didn't find anything which works here .

here is the code and you can see the error in the picture .
thanks

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                  initWithTitle:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:title]
                        message:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:body]
                       delegate:nil
              cancleButtonTitle:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:cancleLable]
              otherButtonTitles:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:firstLable],
 [NSString stringWithUTF8String:secondLable], nil];
[alert show];
```

[image]

Comment: You have extra commas between parameters; they shouldn't be there. Remove the commas, and the code will compile. I am voting to close the question as a typo.

Comment: type in method name `cancleButtonTitle:` should be `cancelButtonTitle:`   -- -- voting to close as typo also